# Referencing Cell Result When Cell Includes Text And Formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell, A1, with the formula:

`="Revenue: $"&sum(B1:B5)`

Let's say the sum of B1 through B5 is $100. I want to then create a cell, A2, with this formula referencing A1's result:

`="Margin: $"&A1-25`

The problem I'm encountering is that A1 includes text when I just want to include the resulting sum. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
="Margin: $"&REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "\$(.*)")-25
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Since the string is always a fixed length you can just say grab everything after the 11th character:

```
="Margin: $"&mid(A1,11,9^9)-25
```